# Tulasi plucking for puja

Tags: tulasi

It is in the [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/why-can-tulsi-leaves-only-be-picked-on-certain-days) that tulasi plucking not allowed on certain days.
And in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/25038/is-tulasi-offered-to-shiva) it I mentioned that tulasi is indispensable.

Question is how do you pick tulasi for pujas on restricted days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Nitya Karm Pooja Prakash by Gita Press](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookNityaKarmPoojaPrakashCompletebyGitaPress/page/n122/mode/1up) - Page 109:

1. You may use Tulsi from previous days.
2. You may use the leaves which are felt down on its own on ground.
3. For Shaligram puja, Tulasi can be plucked on restricted days as well

Comment: Not sure about previous days. Things from previous days a not suitable in most cases.

Comment: @SHebbar Few things such as Tulasi and Gangajal are exceptions..

Comment: @Knowledge Pls add reference, you can find one reference [here](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookNityaKarmPoojaPrakashCompletebyGitaPress/page/n122/mode/1up)