# Does durga mata become happy if her bhakta wears tulsi mala?

Tags: durga

Does durga mata become happy if her bhakta wears tulsi?

Comment: There is no relation as such between Goddess Durga and Tulasi mala. Tulasi mala is dear to Vaishnavas (devotees of Lord Vishnu).

Comment: Shakta deities are beyond the three gunas - Sattava, Rajas, and Tamas.
They are beyond any duality, including happiness/sadness. When we study/pray the nature of Brahman through the personification of Brahman through shaguna forms, it doesn't translate totally into the human form that includes feelings for them. The nature of brahman/Ishvara/devi is not dependent on the materialistic plane either.

Comment: See this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/25041/4732